# Selecting a proper Docker base image

Tags: docker

What is the advantage over using a heavy base image like Ubuntu 14.04 than a lightweight one like Alpine? Is using a sophisticated base image more secure than a light weight one?

Comment: The advantage of a bigger/heavier image is that you have less to install.  The disadvantage is that there is more code installed, some of which you may not need, and any of which might be a security risk.  In general, less code means fewer opportunities for security problems in the code — the safest (securest) code is the code that isn't there.

Comment: and it is quicker to build a new image for any reason, and lighter to deploy

Comment: @JonathanLeffler What if the code that is installed is something like apparmor? I am not disagreeing here, just pointing out what you said is true in most cases, but not all.

Comment: @MattSchuchard What if we install apparmor on host OS then use a light weight base image? Will that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size. `Heavy image` as you put it, will be big and not as fast to pull as a `lightweight image`. The base alpine image is around 5MB (that is the same size as the Windows Start button).

For example alpine-based image with mysql is 16MB while an equivalent image based on ubuntu is 232MB. Thats more than 14 times bigger than it should be. I can't think of a reason you would need a mysql image to be based on ubuntu.

So, the [advantages](https://www.brianchristner.io/docker-is-moving-to-alpine-linux/) are:

- **the speed**: lightweight image is downloaded, installed and run much faster
- **security**: improved security as the image has a smaller footprint
- **migration**: faster migration between hosts
- **disk space**: you will use much less disk space